# Run an iOS6 App on New iPad

Tags: ios, screen, iphone-5

Im creating an App for iPhone5 and it runs good in iPhone 6.0 simulator (with 4-inch display). Now i wanna test it on my New iPad, which has been upgrade to iOS6, but the screen is automatically shrinking into 3.5-inch. Is there anyway to keep the screen being 4-inch on New iPad? Thanks in advance:)

Comment: What's yoour approach for showing views in iPad?

Comment: I don't think that it would make sense to have that mode.  The "2x" button would make the view stretch right off the screen.

Comment: @OhhMee A size with 640x1136px 4-inch screen.

Comment: @borrrden Good point, but apple can make the 2x mode to be 2x 3.5inch but not 2x 4-inch :)

Comment: But why bother?  There is no point...that mode is a backup mode for people who don't make universal apps, it is not meant to be used as a primary mode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "compatibility mode" on iPad runs iPhone-only apps in their 320x480 format—in essence, it is compatible with iPhone <5. There is no way to make it compatible with the 320x568 format used by iPhone 5 and iPod touch (3rd Gen).

So it will *always* run with your app’s "standard" layout, not the "high" one.

Thus, the short answer is "no".